# Object Text Based Java Game Help (Beginner)

Tags: java, class, oop, while-loop, this

So I have to create a Java game. I am very new to Java, and I have been working on this all day. But I can't figure out what is not correct. This is my main class where the game is played. I also have a Character class, a Weapon class, and an Armor class. My problem right now is that I don't want any players' hp to fall below 0. If it falls below 0 it should just be changed to 0, and then that enemy will not be chosen to fight against anymore. I think I am selecting hp wrong somehow, but I don't really understand how. Can anyone help?

````
import Character.Character;

import java.util.Random;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("> Welcome to The Game Project <");
    System.out.println("\n >> Input Main Character Name: ");
    String main_name = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(">> Input Main Character Power: ");
    int main_power=scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(">> Input Main Character Hp: ");
    int main_hp=scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");

    Character main_ch=new Character (main_hp,main_power,main_name);
    show_status(main_ch);
    check_bag(main_ch);

    Character enemies[]=new Character [10];
    enemies[0]= new Character("Werewolf");
    enemies[1]= new Character("Vampire");
    enemies[2]= new Character("Alien");
    enemies[3]= new Character("Witch");
    enemies[4]= new Character("Ghost");
    enemies[5]= new Character("Skeleton");
    enemies[6]= new Character("Zombie");
    enemies[7]= new Character("Demon");
    enemies[8]= new Character("Mummy");
    enemies[9]= new Character("Dragon");

    boolean check = false;
GAME:   
    while(true) {

        Random rnd=new Random();
        int selected = rnd.nextInt(enemies.length); //random enemy selected
        enemies[selected].damage(main_ch.hit_point());

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">>>>> An enemy has appeared and wants to fight! <<<<<");
        show_status(enemies[selected]);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(">> What do you want to do?");
        System.out.println("\t1. Fight!");
        System.out.println("\t2. Run!");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();

        if(input==1) {

            int damageDealt = rnd.nextInt(main_ch.hit_point());
            int damageTaken = rnd.nextInt(main_ch.damage(main_ch.hit_point()));
            enemies[selected].hp -= damageDealt;
            main_ch.hp -= damageTaken;
            System.out.println("You caused "+ damageDealt +" damage to the enemy!");
            System.out.println("You received "+ damageTaken +" damage from the enemy!");
  //        show_status(enemies[selected]);

            if(main_ch.hp ==0) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("\t Oh no! You died! Better luck next time. Thanks for playing!");
                System.out.println();
                break;
                }

            int dead_count=0;
            for(int i=0; i<enemies.length;i++) {
            if(enemies[i].getHp()==0) {
                dead_count=dead_count+1;
            }
            }
            if(dead_count==enemies.length) {
                check=true;
            }
            if(check) {
                System.out.println(">>>>> You won! Congratulations, you defeated all of your enemies! <<<<<");
                break;
           }


        }
        else if(input==2) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("-----You ran away to safety! .... But, uh oh... What is that over there?-----");
                continue GAME;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> Your entry is invalid. <<<<<<<<<<");
        }                        

    }

}
public static void show_status(Character character) {
    System.out.println("----------------- Character Status -----------------");
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Name:\t\t"+character.getName());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter HP:\t\t"+character.getHp());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Power:\t"+character.getPower());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Defense:\t"+character.getDefense());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter MP:\t\t"+character.getMp());
    System.out.println("\tCharacter Level:\t"+character.getLevel());
    System.out.println("\tWeapon Name:\t\t"+character.getWeapon().getName());
    System.out.println("\tWeapon Power:\t\t"+character.getWeapon().getPower());
    System.out.println("\tArmor Name:\t\t"+character.getArmor().getName());
    System.out.println("\tArmor Defense:\t\t"+character.getArmor().getDefense());
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
}
public static void check_bag(Character character) {
    System.out.println("-------------------- Bag Status --------------------");
    System.out.println("\tMoney:\t\t\t$"+ character.getBag().getMoney());
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        System.out.println("\tWeapon Name/Power:\t"+ character.getBag().getWeaponArray()[i].getName()+" // "+character.getBag().getWeaponArray()[i].getPower());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        System.out.println("\tArmor  Name/Defense:\t"+ character.getBag().getArmorArray()[i].getName()+" // "+character.getBag().getArmorArray()[i].getDefense());
    }
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
}```



    This is the code for the Character package:

    ```package Character;
    import java.util.Random;
    import Equipment.*;

    public class Character {
    private Armor armor = new Armor();
    private Weapon weapon = new Weapon();
    private Bag bag = new Bag();

    public int hp, power, defense, mp, level;
    private String name;
    Random rnd=new Random(); 

    public Character(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        Random rnd=new Random();
        this.hp=rnd.nextInt(1000)+1;
        this.power=rnd.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.defense=rnd.nextInt(10)+1;
        this.mp=rnd.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.level=1;
}
    public Character(int hp, int power, String name) {
        this.hp=hp;
        this.power=power;
        this.name=name;
        this.defense=rnd.nextInt(10)+1;
        this.mp=rnd.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.level=1;
}
    public int getHp() {
        return hp;
}
    public void setHp(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
}
    public int getPower() {
        return power;
}
    public void setPower(int power) {
        this.power = power;
}
    public int getDefense() {
        return defense;
}
    public void setDefense(int defense) {
        this.defense = defense;
}
    public int getMp() {
        return mp;
}
    public void setMp(int mp) {
        this.mp = mp;
}
    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
}
    public void setLevel(int level) {
        this.level = level;
        if(this.hp==0) {
            this.level = this.level + 1;
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
}
    public int damage(int enemy_power) {
        int damage = enemy_power - this.defense;
        if(damage<0){ //avoid healing by damage
            damage=0;
}
        this.hp=this.hp - damage;
        if(this.hp<0) { //avoid negative hp
            this.hp = 0;
}
        return damage;
}

    public Armor getArmor() {
    return armor;
}
    public void setArmor(Armor armor) {
        this.armor = armor;
}
    public Weapon getWeapon() {
        return weapon;
}
    public void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
}

    public int hit_point() {
        int total_power = this.power + this.weapon.getPower();
        return total_power;
    }

    public Bag getBag() {
        return bag;
    }
    public void setBag(Bag bag) {
        this.bag = bag;
    }

    public class Bag{
        Weapon weaponArray[] = new Weapon[4];
        Armor armorArray[] = new Armor[4];
        int money = 150;
        public Bag(){
            for(int i=0; i<weaponArray.length; i++) {
                weaponArray[i] = new Weapon();
                armorArray[i] = new Armor();
            }
        }
        public Weapon[] getWeaponArray() {
            return weaponArray;
        }
        public void setWeaponArray(int yourWeaponIndex, Weapon enemyWeapon) {
            this.weaponArray[yourWeaponIndex] = enemyWeapon;
        }
        public Armor[] getArmorArray() {
            return armorArray;
        }
        public void setArmorArray(Armor[] armorArray) {
            this.armorArray = armorArray;
        }
        public int getMoney() {
            return money;
        }
        public void setMoney(int money) {
            this.money = money;
        }

    }
}```

I will also have to figure out a few more things like how to increase the main character's level whenever they kill an enemy. increase the hit_point and decreased the mp if a skill is used (by the way, does anyone know what mp stands for?), and switch out weapons and armor with a dead enemy if theirs is better than mine.
````

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem right here:

```
if(main_ch.hp ==0)
```

After applying damage to the character, you check to see if the character's HP is *exactly* zero. If the character takes a hit leaving 1 or more HP, then combat can continue. If the character takes a hit leaving less than 0 HP, combat can still continue. Only if the character takes an amount of damage reducing HP to precisely 0 will the combat stop.

Luckily, you've already described the fix:

> If it falls below 0 it should just be changed to 0

That can be accomplished like so:

// Changed conditional from exactly zero to less than or equal to zero

```
if(main_ch.hp <= 0) {

    // Added code to reset health

    main_ch.setHp(0);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\t Oh no! You died! Better luck next time. Thanks for playing!");
    System.out.println();
    break;
}
```

On an unrelated note, you may want to rethink the way you're using loops in this code. You could make your code more elegant and easier to read by avoiding all the labelled continues and break statements and just use nested while loops to do what you want, something like this:

```
while(playerWantsToPlay)
{
    // Oh noes! An encounter. Fight or run away bravely?

    while(combatInProgress)
    {
        if(characterIsAlive && targetIsAlive)
        {
            // bash each other in the face
        }
    }
}
```

I think you can guess how to change the conditionals based on game conditions and player choice to control the flow of the game without jumping back and forth with `continue` and `break`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I thought this piece of code in the Characters class was already converting any value below 0 to 0:                     public int damage(int enemy_power) {
        int damage = enemy_power - this.defense;
        if(damage<0){ //avoid healing by damage
            damage=0;
}
        this.hp=this.hp - damage;
        if(this.hp<0) { //avoid negative hp
            this.hp = 0;
}
        return damage;
}                             Am I somehow not using this anywhere, and that is why it isn't working?

Comment: Yeah. That code you have there seems to set the damage amount to zero, as opposed to the character's health. It says "if the damage done is less than zero, make the damage zero." What you really want is "if the character's health is less than zero, make char health zero". Anyhow, if this answer helped you, please click the checkmark on the left to let future readers know what worked for you. Feel free to post more questions as they arise.